# Make the checkbox meta field checked by default

Tags: plugins, custom-field, post-meta

I have created a page for plugin. For that page i have added a checkbox meta field. The field is working fine. 
By default, the checkbox field is unchecked. I mean at first to active the plugin, the checkbox field is unchecked. 
But I need to make it check by default. I have tried a condition but not working at all. My code is :

```
function ins_street_address_shortcode_callback(){
    $val = get_option('ins_street_address_shortcode');

    $checkval = "";

    if ($val == 'on'){
        $checkval = "checked";
    }

    printf("<input type='checkbox' name='ins_street_address_shortcode' %s />", $checkval);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your code is working, as long as `$val == 'on'`.

Did you try debugging by doing `echo $val` ?

If it's still not working, try *hard refreshing* (Ctrl + F5) your webpage, checkboxes tend to keep their state on normal refresh (F5).

Also, please put your code directly on this forum, so the code is always accessible for future viewers ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a HTML checkbox to be checked by default just add "checked" attribute:

`printf("<input type='checkbox' name='ins_street_address_shortcode' %s /> checked", $checkval);`

Comment: I have also tried it. It works but it keeps checked always. When I unchecked it, it becomes checked automatically. How can I fix it?